# GPU Memoryerror while using pytorch with empty GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, memory-leaks, pytorch

I am using HW setup with 3 GPUs, and want to train my model with following code :

```
with torch.cuda.device(2):
    train_load, val_load = SRD.load_sr_st_dataset(route_img,route_dpt)
    #print(train_load.dataset.__sizeof__())
    sr_stereo = SRD.sr_stereo(max_d=200)
    sr_stereo.cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(sr_stereo.parameters(),lr = 0.001)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer,
            milestones=range(5,100,5), gamma=0.5, last_epoch=-1)
    sr_stereo.train()

    for e in range(epoch_num):
        scheduler.step()
        for sample,valid in zip(train_load,val_load):
            l10,l20,r10,r20,depth = SRD.parsedata(sample)
            l10v, l20v, r10v, r20v, depthv = SRD.parsedata(valid)
            out_train = sr_stereo(l10,l20,r10,r20)
            out_val = sr_stereo(l10v, l20v, r10v, r20v)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss_train = criterion(out_train,depth)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()
```

Since I already have 2 models being trained in GPU0 and GPU1 , I want this model to be run at GPU2.

And I got error :

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 282.00 MiB (GPU 2; 31.88 GiB total capacity; 29.99 GiB already allocated; 78.81 MiB free; 30.04 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Is there anything that I am missing ? I cannot understand why the error occurs since GPU 2 has plenty of memory and does not run any training.

Comment: It pretty clearly tells you that the memory is full. How large is your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvidia-smi` command in terminal to check how much memory is accessible. It is crystal clear that you are lack of memory. I assume you do not have enough memory for loading your model on GPU#2.